# How to replace the 'break'?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, break

In my program I have a structure similar to the following one:

```
while (true) {
    int c;
    cout << "Type a command: ";
    cin >> command;
    switch (c) {
        case 1:
            // [...]
            if (!condition) break;
            // [...]
            if (!condition2) break;
            // [...]
            if (!condition3) break;
            // [...]
            break;

        case 2:
            // [...]
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But our professor told us to never use the `break` except in the switch case to exit... I was wondering if there's a better and smarter way to replace the block `if(!condition) break;`.

My main goal is to prevent the program from doing certain actions if `condition` is not verified.

Comment: But every `break` in this code *does* exit the `switch`. None of them exit the loop. *"never use the break except in the switch case to exit"* \*facepalm\*

Comment: You are inside a switch case, so I don't understand your issue.

Comment: Use `goto`, that'll teach him for giving silly assignments.

Comment: You could use an `if else if` ladder than using break. `goto` is a bad practice for sure.

Comment: One option is to place the loop inside a function and then return from the function. Whether that's better than `break`, I'll leave to theorists.

Comment: please show real code. The question is unclear because your `break`s do exit the switch. This might be a misunderstanding because you left out pieces, in any case you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I realised I wasn't explaining it very well while I was writing, but english is not my first language. What the professor said is to use the break only **at the end** of the switch cases...

Comment: @RetiredNinja That's a good idea lol

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid `break` you need to use the opposite condition, and instead of breaking the flow, control it:

```
switch (c) {
    case 1:
        // [...]
        if (condition) {
            // [...]
            if (condition2) {
                // [...]
                if (condition3) {
                    // [...]
                }  // if the third condition is false, you will continue to the break.
            }  // if the second condition is false, you will continue to the break.
        } // if the first condition is false, you will continue to the break.
        break;
    // ...
}
```

### EDIT

To avoid complex conditions, you can use functions:

```
void condition_1_actions();
void condition_2_actions();
void condition_3_actions();

// ... main ...

case 1:
    if (condition) condition_1_actions();
    break;

// ... After main ...

condition_1_actions() {
    // do some actions
    // Calculate condition2 or pass it as parameter
    if (condition2) condition_2_actions();
}

condition_2_actions() {
    // do some actions
    // Calculate condition3 or pass it as parameter
    if (condition3) condition_3_actions();
}

condition_3_actions() {
    // do some actions
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's exactly what I was trying to avoid, because there are loads of conditions and I would end up writing out of my notebook; but apparently there aren't other solutions...

Comment: @JohnBardeen see my edit, I think I gave you a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that "your professor" would agree: *"if it ain't broke, don't fix it."*

The logic as-written is *clear,* and I presume that it *works.*  Also, as-written it would be *maintainable:* I wouldn't have to radically change the source-code <strike>if</strike> *when* I needed to add a new condition to it.  Just leave it alone.  Anything that you hear from a professor – or anyone else – is a *guideline!*

*"Clarity"* is always key, because as years go by your source-code is going to be added-to by many others.  I like the original idiom because each of the cases is clearly distinct:  "make this test, and then bail-out."  (Could be `break` or `return` depending on the situation.)  It's very easy to see how the logic goes, and it's equally easy to add another case to it "in the same vein."

In the end – "it makes absolutely no difference to the digital computer." (As Perl programmers like to say, *"there's more than one way to do it.™")*  But it might be attractive to your *[future ...]* colleagues.  There are no absolutes here.  Just try to be nice to them.  Be "stupid-obvious."

Comment: the the professer is grading the assignment then his opionion is more than "just a guideline" ;)

Comment: That's the point... Even if I do not agree with him I'm forced to follow his rules for this project...

Comment: Operated under a coding standard with a One `return` at the bottom of the function policy at a couple companies. It forced people to simplify their functions, but sometimes it horribly complicated the function instead. Regardless we lived.